# Acetaldoxime Synthesis: Hydroxylamine vs Hydroxylamine HCl

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

Wikipedia says acetaldoxime can be prepared by reacting Acetaldehyde & Hydroxylamine in the presence of NaOH. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetaldoxime

But the reaction shown uses Hydroxylamine Hydrochloride instead of Hydroxylamine.

Does it not matter? Do both work? Would Hydroxylamine Sulfate work as well?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hydroxylamine is a low-boiling liquid readily oxidized to explosive nitrogen-oxygen compounds.  It is stored as the hydroxylammonium hydrochloride salt for convenience and safety, since the salts do not oxidize as easily.  Additionally, hydroxylamine itself may explode when heated.

The sodium hydroxide is to render the freebase which then may participate in the reaction.  In principle, the hydroxylammonium bisulphate would work as well.

It is somewhat important that an exact stoichiometry be used for base to hydroxylamine to prevent aldol side-reactions if relevant (which for acetaldehyde, they are).  Additionally, this reaction is reversible in the presence of acid and water, so all the acid must be consumed, since water is a byproduct of the condensation.  Given the explosive nature of hydroxylamine, azeotropic distillation via Dean-Stark trap is not viable for dehydration.  Chemical dehydration may be effective.

Comment: Thanks! What you refer to as the bisulfate, is that this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxylammonium_sulfate

Comment: For commercial quantity use at scale I seem to get three options from BASF: The freebase, the HCl salt, the sulfate. http://www.intermediates.basf.com/chemicals/inorganic-specialities/hydroxylamine-free-base-and-salts I'm working out the economics of each option. Funnily they do ship the freebase in  spite of the risks, but just as a 50% solution in H2O

Comment: @curious_cat, that link points to the sulphate (not the bisulphate).  The sulphate may also work, but you will need two equivalents of base, and also gain two equivalents of hydroxylamine from the reagent.  The sulphate is (obviously) non-halogenated, so it will probably be cheaper to get rid of, even if the mass of waste is higher.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the bisulphate made  / sold in tonnage quantities. So forced to choose from the freebase / chloride or sulfate.

Comment: Interestingly the sulfate vs HCl salt is pricing agnostic. i.e. Per equivalent of Hydroxylamine produced the cost is the same. The freebase on the other hand is 3x as expensive. Not sure why.

Comment: Explosion hazard.  Shipping hazard.  Liquid.

Comment: Another question: Just like the Hydrochloride Salt needs NaOH to render the freebase if one used the Sulfate salt would one use a co-reagent to render the freebase? What would be this co-reagent?

Comment: NaOH, two equivalents